# How to store db table entries as documents in CouchDB?

Tags: json, postgresql, couchdb, rdbms

I tried out this script:

```
table_name = "table_name"
psql -d db_name -t -c "select array_to_json(array_agg(s)) from $table_name s" -o data.json

curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/$table_name

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @data.json http://localhost:5984/test_db/_bulk_docs
```

This works fine for me, except the file data.json. In this only json object array is present. But in order to save those docs in CouchDB we must have "docs" label refer to that array.

Example - 
data i'm getting

```
[
{
 "id" : 1,
 "name" : "Bharat"
}, 
{
 "id" : 2,
 "name" : "Ravan"
}
]
```

Data i want -

```
{
"docs" : [
{
 "id" : 1,
 "name" : "Bharat"
}, 
{
 "id" : 2,
 "name" : "Ravan"
}
]
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Only lowercase characters are allowed in DB names, as states the error message, testDB is not a valid name, try testdb

Comment: I resolved that thing, let me edit my question.

Comment: "id" field should be "_id"

Comment: @JuanjoRodriguez, this is just the json array data that i'll get from some rdbms table